# Laravel - send mail to queue with different connection

Tags: php, laravel, email, queue

I use this code to send invoice

```
        Mail::send($email_template, $view_vars, static function ($m) use ($customer, $company, $email_subject, $users, $invoice, $invoice_name) {
        $m->from($company->send_email, $company->name);
        $m->to($users, $customer->getFullName())->subject($email_subject);
        $m->attachData($invoice, $invoice_name);
    });
```

Problem that it need some time to send email with atache.
Decision - to use Queue and change Mail::send() to Mail::queue()

But I use iron.io as as QUEUE Driver. And by default email with attached will go to iron.io - so it also need some time.

I whant to use database connection for this case.

can I use code:

```
Mail::queue(.......)->onConnection('database');
```

?

Table `Jobs` already exist.
After this need I some additional code that emails was realy sended in background ot it will be done automaticaly?

Comment: Tha best way is to use local connection method (databases) for all queues.

Answer (score 0):

According to Laravel docs, you can use onConnection with Queues.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#chain-connection-queue

To do extra processing after mail has been sent, you need to listen to Laravel's MailSent event.
https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Mail/Events/MessageSent.html

1. Define a listener in EventServiceProvider

```
'Illuminate\Mail\Events\MessageSent' => [
   'App\Listeners\OnMessageSent',
]
```

2. Define handle function in the listener.

```
use Illuminate\Mail\Events\MessageSent;

class OnMessageSent {

    // listen for MailSent event
    public function handle(MessageSent $event)
    {
        if ($event) {
            // do something here
            dd($event);
        }
    }
}
```